# Add a value in one cell when the date is in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a shopping list of things that I would like to buy.

I have the items in Column B (1-1006) and when I buy these items I put the following formula in Column J {=char(10004)} and I have a conditional format that changes the colour of Column B to black from grey when I use the formula from above.

What is my query if I put a date (1/5/2018) in column G? Is there a way for Column H to have the char(10004) automatically appear in there?

Comment: Take a look at the ISDATE and the IF functions. You'll want the IF to check if the cell is a date. If it is show the check mark

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There is also a relatively simple option based on their being a tick in all of ColumnH all the time (formatted the same colour as its background, unless that is black) but having it *appear* only when there is a date in ColumnG of the same row.

Select ColumnH, clear any CF from it and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is:

```
=isdate(G1)
```

with black for Font colour and <kbd>Done</kbd>.